# Infinite loading php page while opening a python file

Tags: python, php, html, css

I'm pretty new in including Python in a PHP site. I am creating a Python Alarm Clock witch should open different webpages which are located on my PC. I have a PHP page which automatically opens up on startup in which I can put in the time to wake up. When I press "Save" it should start the python file, which then should open up another page and start the clock. My problem is now that the starting page is infinitely loading and nothing happens. What have I done wrong.

My code is the following:

index.php:

```php
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $Name = "".$_POST['username']."
  ";
  $Pass = "".$_POST['password']."
  ";
  $file=fopen("saved.txt", "a");
  fwrite($file, $Name);
  fwrite($file, $Pass);
  fclose($file);

$command = escapeshellcmd('python /home/lul/Desktop/wecker.py');
   $output = shell_exec($command);
   echo $output;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>My HTML Form</title>
</head>
<body class="blogdesire-body">
  <div class="blogdesire-wrapper">
    <div class="blogdesire-heading">
      My HTML Form
    </div>
    <form class="blogdesire-form" method="post">
      <input type="number" name="username" placeholder="Hour" required autocomplete="off"> <br>
      <input type="number" name="password" placeholder="Minutes" required autocomplete="off"> <br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SAVE" class="blogdesire-submit">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

python code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import webbrowser
import datetime
import os

print('Try opening file')

fileHandler = open ("/var/www/html/saved.txt")

listOfLines = fileHandler.readlines()

fileHandler.close()

hours = int(listOfLines[0])

minutes = int(listOfLines[1])

print(hours, minutes)
print(datetime.datetime.now().hour, datetime.datetime.now().minute)

os.remove("/var/www/html/saved.txt")

webbrowser.open("file:///home/lul/Desktop/startup/clock.html")

print("Done Opening")

while (1 == 1):
    if (hours == datetime.datetime.now().hour and minutes == datetime.datetime.now().minute):
        webbrowser.open("file:///home/lul/Desktop/morning/morning.html")

print('Sup')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have missed it, but you have a

```
while(1==1)
```

in the python script.That will execute the next 2 lines indefinetly

Comment: yes i do but i want to open the other page before it starts the while loop. With the first Webbrowser.open and that never happens.

Comment: no it doesnt. But in testing I got some errors from the python file so I think its actually opening the .py file

Comment: The errors are fixed. Mow I dont get any errors but also nothing happens

Comment: Sadly when I type the path in to my browser by myself it opens up normaly